# How should I define and use a custom module Exception?

Tags: module, magento-1, exception

I want to create a custom Magento exception class for my module.

Are there any rules for how I should do it? Where should I put the new class? How should it be thrown?

I'm familiar with `Mage::throwException()`, should it be done like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are there any rules for how I should do it?

Yes. If you take a look at `app/Mage.php` in the `exception()` method, you will see that it looks for an exception that matches the pattern `$module . '_Exception`, for example: `YourCompany_YourModule_Exception`:

```
/**
 * Return new exception by module to be thrown
 *
 * @param string $module
 * @param string $message
 * @param integer $code
 * @return Mage_Core_Exception
 */
public static function exception($module = 'Mage_Core', $message = '', $code = 0)
{
    $className = $module . '_Exception';
    return new $className($message, $code);
}
```

> Where should I put the new class?

Because of the way this method works you have no control over where your exception is placed - **it must be placed in the module root directory,** and it must be named `MyCompany_MyModule_Exception`. For example:

```
# File: app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Exception.php
class MyCompany_MyModule_Exception extends Mage_Core_Exception
{

}
```

This is the way it is because the Magento autoloader will work the same way it does for other Magento classes in that it looks for an `Exception` file in the `MyCompany/MyModule` folder.

> How should it be thrown?

Use the `exception()` method instead of `throwException()`. The former will throw an exception from a custom module, whereas the latter will throw a `Mage_Core_Exception`:

```
if (false === $myResult) {
    throw Mage::exception('YourCompany_YourModule', 'My result was false');
}
```

Catch:

```
try {
    $this->doSomething();
} catch (YourCompany_YourModule_Exception $ex) {
    var_dump('Caught custom exception:' . $ex->getMessage());
}
```

---

#### More specific exceptions

A side note, if you want to make your exceptions more specific to certain parts of your module, e.g. a certain Model, you can create Exception classes and put them whereever you want, as long as they follow the correct Magento naming convention for a class. You wouldn't use the method above to throw them however, you'd just have to throw them the old fashioned way:

```
# File: app/code/local/YourCompany/YourModule/Model/Connector/Exception.php
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Connector_Exception extends Mage_Core_Exception
{

}
```

Then throw it like this:

```
throw new YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Connector_Exception('The connection broke.');
```