# Overriding default magento exception handler

Tags: magento-1.9, exception

How would I aproach this? Everything I found so far informed me about `extending` magento exception handler, although I want to `override`, or if it's not possible then call my custom handler when exception is thrown / error is found, the default magento exception handler so I can do and print whatever I want, where should I start?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118158/how-should-i-define-and-use-a-custom-module-exception

Answer (score 0):

You can **enable/disable** showing some exceptions in root directory, index.php file. Just comment `if` statement and leave what is between brackets:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

also, you can use:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```